# Application development in Ubuntu using C++

Tags: 12.10, programming, c++

I want to write applications for Ubuntu. I do not know much about programming, but I want develop for Ubuntu. I am trying to learn C++ right now. What do you think is the best way to develop apps for Ubuntu ?

Comment: http://developer.ubuntu.com/
http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/

Answer (score 0):

If you are just learning C++, I would recommend you write simple programs using the vi editor and compile them using g++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeblocks until you are more familiar with the C++ language. Just visit the codeblocks website http://www.codeblocks.org and select the linux download. Select the binary release, then your linux version, then download the bigger file. Also I'd recommend Deitel & Deitel books or Head First for C++ if you want to get to learn C++ better.

One more thing to note. If you plan to write the code on Windows, then you'll have to compile the cpp file on Ubuntu